# sharepoint 2010 permissions on a page

Tags: permissions, navigation

It seems that sp has the following ootb behaviour when a user/group's persmission is removed from a page - SP hides the navigation link to that page.

I am looking for the following behaviour (if possible).

1. User navigates to a page for which he does not have permission to view.
2. User receives a message (instead of the page content) that they should contact the helpdesk if they wish access.

Is there a way to stop sharepoint from hiding the links and to redirect to a default "access denied" page??

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint security trims things people don't have access to automatically.  To work around that, you have to provide a hard coded navigation structure so that a user can see the links they do not have access to so that when they click on it, they'll receive the access denied screen.

Comment: Thought so - bummer! Microsoft miss the boat too often!

Comment: I'm in the other camp, the automatic security trimming is a good thing.

Comment: Depends on your particular scenario I guess.